# How do I conditionally call a proxy server based on route params?

Tags: hapi.js

```
let post = 
{
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/posts/new/{postType}',
  handler: (request, reply) =>{
       //when params is text
  if (request.params.postType == "text") 
  {
    return reply("successfully uploaded text post");
  }
   //when params is image
  else (request.params.postType == "image") 
  {
    //call proxy uri to save the image
    /*proxy: 
     {
         uri: proxyUri + '/post/image', //call proxy uri to save the image
         passThrough: true,
         acceptEncoding: false,
      }*/
   }
 }
```

How do I conditionally call a proxy server based on route params so I use one rest api for post text, image, vides etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reply.proxy](https://github.com/hapijs/h2o2#replyproxyoptions)().

```
const route = {
    /* ... */
    handler: (request, reply) => {
        if (request.params.useproxy) {
            return reply.proxy({host: 'example.com', port: 80, protocol: 'http'});
        } else {
            return reply('no proxy');
        }
    }
};
```